# NGRX data entityResourceUrl depending on other entity. dynamic urls?

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

Usually when I want to specify url of the entity I have one specific url for it like **serverURL/heroes**.
But now I have a case where I want to use entity belonging to other entity. For example lets say I want to use weapons of heroes. My http urls for swords look something like: **serverURL/heroes/heroID/weapons**. So lets say I need to add new sword, my only option is to add it to a specific hero, so I need to know heroesID and sword information to do something like: HTTP POST `http.post('serverURL/heroes/heroID/weapons', swordObject);`

Currently when I just add heroes url in entityHttpResourceUrls in DefaultDataServiceConfig. You can see the [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-3edjub). go to app->store->entity-> entity-store.module.ts. that's where I usually specify the url.

**How do I approach my case? how can I have dynamic urls for child entities?**

**Update**

from what I've found in this issue, ngrx-data doesn't support parameters yet.

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1934

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using getWithQuery function:

```
getWithQuery(params: QueryParams): Observable<Weapon[]> {

    const hero= params['heroId'] || '';
    const pageIndex = params['pageIndex'] || '0';
    const pageSize = params['pageSize'] || '25';
    const apiUrl = `api/hero/${heroId}/weapons/?page=${pageIndex}&size=${pageSize}`

    return this.http.get(apiUrl)
}
```

instead of using getAll.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I created service:

```
@Injectable()
export class OrganizationDataService extends DefaultDataService<Organization> {
  constructor(http: HttpClient, httpUrlGenerator: DefaultHttpUrlGenerator, logger: Logger) {
    super('Organization', http, httpUrlGenerator);
  }

  getAll(): Observable<Organization[]> {
    console.log('getAll called');
    // custom call to api correct variant:
    return this.execute('GET', `${environment.apiUrl}org/${someId}/apps`)
    // custom call to api also worked variant:
    // return this.http.get<Organization[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}org/${someId}/apps`);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I am doing now, but this only returns the observable It doesn't work with store.

Comment: @Vladymyr K Where does someId come from? That's my issue right now.

Comment: @Godrules500 did you manage to figure this out? having the same issue

Comment: @Vato, you need to register the service
https://ngrx.io/api/data/EntityDataService#registerService

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [router store](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store) from NGRX.

With the store, you have this selectors:

`selectQueryParams`, `selectRouteParams`, `selectRouteData` and the `selectUrl`.

So you can easily get all your needs to build the different paths.